# Arc length of epicycloid when small radius goes to 0

Tags: calculus, limits, curves, arc-length

So I've been working out on epicycloids and I got the arc length formula, let's say for a lap around the big circumference. Big radius is $R$ and small radius going around is $r$. Then that formula is $8(R+r)$. Now, intuitively, one can argue that this length should be the length of the big circumference when the radius $r$ goes to 0, because the curve is approaching that. However, it is clear that $\lim_{r\to 0} 8(R+r) = 8R$, which is clearly not equal to $2\pi R$, the length of the circumference. Hence, intuition failed to work. I would appreciate if anyone could give me an explanation for why they are different. My guess is that every little arc is becoming steeper when approaching radius 0, not smoother, so it won't approach $2\pi R$, but that's too vague. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your dilemma now. Say that $m=a+b$ is fixed and we let $b=1/n$, where $n$ is an integer, so that we satisfy the condition that $m/b$ is indeed an integer. Now, what happens when we let $n\to \infty$? We can never actually achieve $b=0$. It's sort of like Zeno's paradox; we just can't get there. I demonstrated this numerically, i.e., for any value of $n$ the arc length is $L=8m$. If you plot this for large $n$ it *looks* like a circle, but it isn't. There are a large number of cusps and adding up the total length always gives the same result. If you try to *force* $b=0$ then you are confronted with the problem that $m/b$ is not really defined. At the same time, we can look at the area enclosed, which I believe to be $A=\pi m(m-b)$, we see that area of the epicycloid approaches that of the circle of larger radius for large $n$.

Comment: I guess it makes sense. Infinite stuff gets messy. The idea that $m/b$ won't be an integer so we can't make $b=0$ also makes sense. I think that was what you were trying to tell me before  but I didn't understand it then. It's also quite interesting that the area does approach that of the circumference. Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

According to *A Catalog of Special Plane Curves*, J. Dennis Lawrence, Dover, 1972, the equations for the epicycloid are

$$x=m\cos t-b\cos mt/b\\
y=m\sin t-b\sin mt/b
$$

where $t\in[-\pi,\pi]$ and $m=a+b$ (i.e., the radii).

However, it states that $L=8m$ (**if $m/b$ is an integer**). Therein lies your problem.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't see how that helps my problem. Let's say a=3, b=1. Then I know the arc length for the epicycloid is $8*(3+1)=32$, but I was trying to figure out why wouldn't this arc length approach the arc length of the 3 radius circumference when the other one approaches radio 0. In other words, I would like to know why doesn't it equal $2πa$ in the limit as b goes to 0, as one would think intuitively, the epicycloid would fit the shape of the big circumference.